# How to resolve multiple then() promise into one

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fetch

In this code I used multiple `then()` methods, I just want to convert it into only one then, How it is possible.

```
getGreeting = () => {
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((result) => result.data)
    .then((data) => printCards(data))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```

Comment: whats wrong with this solution? it looks clean and readable

Comment: Its a good solution and should not be changed. Nevertheless, it could be improved by changing `.then((data) => printCards(data))` to `.then(printCards)` which is the same

Comment: The second then block is not returning a Promise, I reckon. You could finish it in two then blocks instead of threee.

Comment: If I am  using async and await is it a good option that multiple then() methods or not?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

notice the `async` and `await` keywords

```
fetch(url)
    .then(async (response) => {
      const json = await response.json();
      printCards(json.data);
     })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};
```